# Shrink GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if GROUP BY is the right way to achive what I am looking for.
Assume you have a table like

```
UID     ID     VERSION  A       B       C
------------------------------------------------
1       1       3       'a'     NULL    NULL
2       1       2       NULL    'b'     NULL
3       1       1       NULL    NULL    'c'
4       2       3       NULL    'dd'    NULL
5       2       2       NULL    'd'     'e'
6       2       1       'f'     NULL    NULL
```

Now I want to select some kind of shrinked rows by grouping/selecting on `ID` sorting the group by `VERSION`(`DESC`) and then only use the first matching `NOT NULL` cell.

The result should be (`VERSION` not specified)

```
ID      VERSION  A       B       C
-----------------------------------------
1       3        'a'     'b'     'c'
2       3        'f'     'dd'    'e'
```

or with specific `VERSION` using s.th like `WHERE version <= 2`

```
ID      VERSION  A       B       C
-----------------------------------------
1       2        NULL    'b'     'c'
2       2        'f'     'd'     'e'
```

Im not even sure if it makes sense to versionize like this. I was thinking of cells with large content where only some columns are frequently changed and it would be a huge overhead to copy the other unchanged columns on every change.

Comment: are you trying to only get the row corresponding to the max version for each "ID"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not myself think of anything else but GROUP BY.

Why don't you try this?

```
SELECT id, MAX(version) as version,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(A ORDER BY version DESC ),',',1)  as A,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(B ORDER BY version DESC ),',',1)  as B,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(C ORDER BY version DESC ),',',1)  as C
FROM table WHERE version <= 2
GROUP BY id;
```

So this -

1. basically groups all the values of As, Bs and Cs respectively (by ordering them by version descending)
2. And then gets the first value of each(before the first comma)

This should work fine as long as you do not hit [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) length limit constraints

Comment: I think you have to add `GROUP BY ID`.

Comment: Stupid me, missed that!!

Comment: ... and use max(version)

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks!
But ... `GROUP_CONCAT` may end up in a very large string if you have a couple of changes in that column. Don't you think this will become a memory/performance problem?

Comment: But in general, do you think this is a "usefull" way of storing data-versions? Or are there better pattern for SQL DBs?
Maybe it's faster to fetch all rows and shrink them using an other language than SQL.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of completeness here the solution for *Oracle* database using analytic functions (that elegantly solve the long group problem)

```
 with lst as (
 select   ID, VERSION, A, B, C,
 last_value(A ignore nulls) over (partition by ID order by VERSION) as LAST_A,
 last_value(B ignore nulls) over (partition by ID order by VERSION) as LAST_B,
 last_value(C ignore nulls) over (partition by ID order by VERSION) as LAST_C,
 row_number() over (partition by ID order by VERSION DESC) as rn
 from tst
 WHERE version <= 2 /* comment out to get all versions */
 )
 select 
   ID, VERSION, LAST_A as A, LAST_B as B, LAST_C as C
 from lst 
 where rn = 1
 order by id;
```